# looking for a field inside a mongodb document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, nosql

I'm trying ask if a field exist inside a document inside another document in an mongodb database using java driver. The field that I asking for is idMovie.

For example, I expect that it print in the console "idMovie value already exist" if idMovie is 2, for example. Or print "not exist" if idMovie is 10, because 10 are not in the document

this is my bson object:

```
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5320aa3c3e468eaeb52dccdc"}, 
   "document" : "movies" , 
   "rateMovies" : [ 
        { 
         "idMovie" : 2 , 
         "average" : "0" , 
         "sum" : "0" , 
         "total" : "0"
        } , 

       { 
         "idMovie" : 3 ,
         "average" : "0" ,
         "sum" : "0" , 
         "total" : "0"
       }]
  }
```

And this is my java code:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient ("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("DBHC2");
        DBCollection movieDocument = db.getCollection("rateMovies");

        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("idMovie", idMovie);
        DBCursor cursor = movieDocument.find(searchQuery);

        /* if is true, the idMovie value already exist in database. */
        if(cursor.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("idMovie value already exist");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not exist");
        }
```

, but don't works for my. Any help is good received, thank you!!

Comment: _"but don't works"_ is not sufficient.  HOW does it not work? What are you seeing that is unexpected? Have you stepped through the code in an IDE debugger?  What did that tell you?

Comment: well, if you follow the java code, I expect that it  print in the console "idMovie value already exist" if idMovie is 2, for example. Or print "not exist" if idMovie is 10 because 10 are not in the document. Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm if the name of your collection is "rateMovies"?

Comment: yes the name is correct

Comment: Can you please post the output of db.rateMovies.findOne() from the shell?

Comment: sorry, you have reason, the collection name is movies, but if I replace `DBCollection movieDocument = db.getCollection("movies");` for `DBCollection movieDocument = db.getCollection("rateMovies");` I steel have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you help, but I find the answer by my self.

```
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient ("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("DBHC2");
        DBCollection movieDocument = db.getCollection("movies");

        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("rateMovies.idMovie", idMovie);
        DBCursor cursor = movieDocument.find(searchQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    searchQuery.put("idMovie", new BasicDBObject("$exists",true));
```

Comment: if you follow the java code, I expect that it print in the console "idMovie value already exist" if idMovie is 2, for example. Or print "not exist" if idMovie is 10, because 10 are not in the document. Thanks.